# Vector, sled being pulled problem

Tags: vectors

A boy drags a sled for 100 feet along the ground by pulling on a rope which
is 20 degrees from the horizontal with a force of 40 pounds. How much work
does this force do?
I have no idea what this question is even asking, please someone help.
Thanks Jack :D

Comment: Could you please provide a picture of the problem?

Comment: This is all I have been given. I understand everything in the question except I don't understand what 'How much work does this force do' means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work done by the force is the component of the force in the direction of the displacement multiplied by the distance.

In this case, it's $40\cos20\times100$ in suitable units

Comment: Thanks this really helped :D

Comment: you are welcome